# LINQ queries vs Stored procedures

Tags: .net, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework

What are the pros and cons of using linq queries(along with an ORM like EF or linq2sql) VS. Stored Procedures(SQL server 2008) to query and update a data model? Performance? Speed? Etc...

Comment: Not quite a duplicate (almost), but see my answer <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517891/are-sps-redundant-if-using-linq-and-ef-best-practice/4517929#4517929">here</a> to see when to use SPROCs or LINQ with Entity Framework.

Comment: You can improve speed of your Linq queries using [compiled queries](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2008/02/19/HighPerformanceLINQToSQLCompiledQueriesORMappersEcommerceWebsites.aspx).

Comment: Wow I should have realized there would not be a cut and dried answer to this. Great answers though so far. I have some thinking to do. I assumed LINQ would have been the clear favorite but I guess its not that simple...

Comment: It does seem to me that MS is pushing the EF/LINQ method...The examples ive seen on asp.net all use EF/LINQ...Is this strictly for demonstration purposes? or are they trying to give us hints?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Linq is definitely more readable when you're in the code.  Seeing a call to execute a sproc called "sp_GetSomething" doesn't tell you anything as a developer, unless you go and physically look at what the sproc does.  seeing code like

```
var query = from c in db.TableName
            where c.Name == "foo"
            select c;
```

That tells you exactly what data is being pulled.

Stored procedures on the other hand do not require you to recompile the application if you decide to change the code.  If you decide to suddenly change a "`where`" clause or change the `Order By` - changing a sproc is easy.  Changing the Linq code could be more time consuming.

I'm sure there are plenty more, but these are two I've noticed.

Comment: it should be == and not = on your sample

Comment: The second part might well be considered a disadvantage. Changing a sproc in a production environment is silent and potentially deadly, whereas changes to code go through version control, build and testing to ensure quality.

Answer (score 9):

There are 2 camps: for stored procs and against stored procs.

I've found that it is lack of experience that make people go one way or another. There are different kinds of shops where we develop.

In practice

- if you're a corporate programmer, then you'll never change your RDBMS platform. You refactor your client every now and and you'll reimplement your DAL/repository. Why? Use stored procs.
- if you work for a vendor, then you will probably have to support several RDBMS. An ORM abstracts this away mostly.

I'm in a corporate shop so...

- Pros: with Linq you don't have to know SQL
- Cons: you're screwed when things go wrong

We (as a developer DBA team) frequently have to bail out ORM users in sister teams.

There are also more subtle issues such that:

- stored procedures can be used by any client
- will outlast your refactor into EF or whatever .net 5 brings
- encapsulation offered by stored procedures to abstract schema away
- reduced round trips because shouldn't stored procs be treated like methods, or atomic calls?

Comment: I have a few in regards to your "have to bail out dev's" - I would say the team needs to hire better developers

Comment: The pro's and con's isn't actually true. You can't write solid Linq code without understanding sql. If you have to bail out sister temas with ORM, then they are juniors who don't understand how an orm works. They need to learn to debug and trace. Stored Procs move the data layer into the database. Linq alleviates a lot of that. In a corporate environment stored procs are rarely used unless you are susing SSIS, SSRS, PP, or sql jobs. In other words, it makes more sense to use link than SP's in a corporate environment. Stored procs have a need for intensive cals, otherwise the DBA has an ego

Comment: "Cons: you're screwed when things go wrong" - Isn't this true for all things.

Answer (score 4):

@gbn has a great answer.

In huge systems with hundreds of millions of records, data manipulation on the presentation layer **just isn't going to cut it**. Data intensive applications (not blogging apps!) will need to scale sooner than you think.

ORM's are a huge time saver when developing a small to medium system. You can have a production ready app in no time with a properly implemented orm. no one likes to write crud.

It is also important to remember SQL syntax has been consistent for over 20 years. If this isn't important to you, you haven't been programming long enough.

Answer (score 3):

I would almost always go with stored procedures for several reasons:

1) Using LINQ in code to query a database is not really following the principles of mult-tier architecture... anything involving accessing database objects should be done at the database level. LINQ queries are just a wrapper for writing SQL in your code. SQL or LINQ in code is a no-no, even though the MVC examples all do it.

2) Performance... stored procedures DO execute faster! Anytime that you are running queries from code, you are prone to scalability and performance issues.

3) Maintenance. Because stored procedures liberate you from having SQL or LINQ in your code, the maintenance for your stored procedures can be taken care of seperately (seperation of concerns).

Comment: I disagree with pretty much everything you have written.

Comment: 2) is verifiably correct 3) is a question of preference and 2) is essentially true - multi-tier architecture dictates that each level or tier of an application should be clearly seperated. If you write database code in your application, you have combined 2 tiers in 1, thus violating the principle... it is that simple.

Comment: Multi-tier can satisfied by simply putting your data access layer in a separate assembly or project. This solves your points 1 & 3. And as for point 2, I'm led to believe the performance difference in SQL2008 are minimal if they exist at all.

Comment: 2) Performance of individual queries may be quicker using stored procedures, but deferred execution can mean that complex business queries built up by chaining queries, sorting, paging, etc. may actually be quicker using Linq.

Comment: And to address some of your points: 1) multi-tier. who said anything about multi tier? As Kirk has said, why not create a application server to talk to the db, and have the web tier communicate (via WCF for example)? "SQL or LINQ in code is a no-no". Ridiculous statement. SQL - i agree, yes. But the beauty of LINQ-Entities, is that your querying against the *model*, not the database. Your not writing "SQL" per se. 2) How are stored procedures more scalable? Can you not optimize LINQ? How about compiled queries? 3) Again, having a good DAL (e.g Repository Pattern) can help you here.

Comment: Overall - the point is the key to a good DAL is a mix of robust yet flexibile and performance. When you have a complicated domain model (inheritance, relationships), EF will ease your pain with it's wealth of tooling support and the consistent framework it's built upon (LINQ). When there are queries that need to be super optimal, use EF to call the SPROCS, or compile your LINQ-Entities queries. I don't think the answer to this question is "Use LINQ for everything", or "Use SPROCS for everything". Use both - but understand *why you need to*, that is the real challenge.

Comment: For point 3 I assume you mean maintenance of stored procedures becomes a bigger pain in the ass because now versioning them becomes more difficult and you need someone with specialized skills (your particular dialect of SQL) to maintain them?

Answer (score 3):

The real answer is it's "horses for courses". From one perspective (as a db dev like @gbn), it's stored procs all the way. From my perspective as a back-office end-to-end web developer, who's app's concurrent usage never gets above 100, and who isn't brilliant at writing efficient SQL, it's LINQ (currently EF 4.1) all the way. And code-first, if I can get away with it. This is the 15th piece I've read on the matter today (after an argument in a dev meeting) and every single piece seems to suggest the same thing - "horses for courses". And sometimes, in a back-office world, it's not just data-fetching-efficiency that you have to take into account - it's how quickly (efficiently) you can fix bugs, and how easily (efficiently) the next person can see what your code is doing. From this perspective, LINQ wins hands down.

Comment: Can you add any insight as to the scalability of EF 4.1 with > 100 concurrent users? what issues would one run into with higher traffic applications?

Comment: It's all relative to your hardware I guess! You can write all the beautiful stored procs in the world but if you've got 1 db server with 1gb of ram and 2 million users, you're gonna be in trouble...

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the SQL Version you use. The execution plan (which is the information used by SQL to make a second call faster ...) in SQL 2008 works really well also with an O/RM.
I don't see why you would use an O/RM and waiste a lot of time by re-mapping everything to custom stored proc.
Also a stored proc. is hardly to be TDD and doesn't allow you the concept of Unit of WOrk and transaction

Answer (score 2):

I would agree with Peter Lee on this one - in a serious, enterprise-scale environment, using stored proc is probably the preferred way to go.

In addition to Peter's comments, here are a few more:

1. The EF or Linq-to-SQL (or NHibernate, too) are ORM's, which means they want to turn a row in your database table into an object. Since that object typically should contain all the values from that table (or even from multiple tables, in the case of EF), those ORM's usually use a `SELECT * FROM ....` approach. This means: since you're selecting all columns, you typically cannot make use of any covering indices, and your performance will hurt. It's a classic "convenience vs. performance" trade-off
2. All ORM's I know of and have worked with basically need full **table access to the base tables**. This is a big no-no for a lot of enterprises and their DBA's. Using stored procedures wisely, you can get by without having to allow all users base table access - a big plus in terms of access security!

Comment: I strongly disagree with your 1st statement:
"SELECT * FROM" approach - does not exist. Have you try to use SQL Server Profiler to see what query is actually executed on the server? LinqToSQL or EF only queries what you ask it for, nothing more.

Comment: @Andrei: and typically, when you have an object that maps 1:1 to a database table, and you want to get an object, you need to get **all** columns - and you get an `SELECT * FROM .....` And **yes**, I've verified this in SQL Profiler.

Comment: Well, I guess it is a matter of how you use your LinqToSql/EF data model. To create an instance of a "row" class - you do not have to query the DB at all. If you have to get only a couple of values and still have to use the auto-generated "row" type, you can do it as following: select new Customer()
{
    FULL_NAME = cx.FULL_NAME,
    OID = cx.OID
}

Comment: @Andrei: agreed - if you use projection to select only a few properties, then Linq-to-SQL and EF both don't use `SELECT * `- that's one way to get around this problem. But that's most likely the 5% case - the vast majority of accesses to the database will be "get the customer no. 4711" and in this case, all the properties need to be populated, and a `SELECT * ...` will occur in the backend.

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer to your question, but don't forget that you can still use [EF on stored procs](http://weblogs.asp.net/kencox/archive/2009/11/25/using-a-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-4.aspx)

Comment: Yes I have been usng Linq2Sql to call my stored procedures for a while. Seems like some combination of the two is going to be the best route.

Answer (score 2):

False dichotomy. IMO, you can get the sweet spot of both by using raw SQL (which is an important skill, that we should not shy away from) with tools that simply make that convenient. Stored procedures introduce some coupling / deployment issues (timing, etc) that most people don't need; ORMs can be poor performing. Most people aren't going to change RDBMS (and if they do, it will be a major project anyway), so: I'm a big fan of parameterized command text. And tools that help, for example, dapper.

Another user posted a LINQ example of filtering by name; well, here's the same in dapper:

```
string name = ...
var list = connection.Query<YourType>(
    "select * from TableName where Name=@name",
    new { name }).ToList();
```

Fully parameterized; havily optimized; safe; quick; clean; easy to get right. Job done.

Answer (score 2):

A lot has been said already in response to the original question. My answer is based on commercial aspects and not technical. Here is my experience, perhaps it will give some pointers to some who are starting new projects.  We started with Asp.net + SQL Server and the application grew into a complicated one using about 800 stored procedures.  For three years we go free SQL server through a Microsoft program so never cared early on.  When the licensing quote of over 50K hit the table (its based on number of cores/threads and you also need a separate license for slave server), we ran to migrate to MySQL.  **Wish we were not using stored procedures.**  Without stored procedures, we could easily migrate quickly, within a few days.  Took us much longer and great efforts to rewrite SPs into MySQL. If you are not using SPs, your app is more flexible/portable and it is easier to debug code within your app itself.

So if not technical, from commercial viewpoint there is a strong case against using stored procedures in web applications.  If not using SPs, you may also distribute your app to customers with db schema (which will include tables only) while your application logic is still hidden in Linq+EF or Linq SQL.

Answer (score 0):

My preference is LINQ, checking the queries produced in a tool like EF Profiler. If any generated queries are too long or create N+1s, they can normally be fixed. Once in production I keep my eye on the stats and if a slow query can't be fixed by caching I will move it to a stored procedure.

The main advantages to doing your queries in linq are:

- Easy to source control and deploy query changes
- Queries are compiled so if you change/rename something you know if you've broken something
- Can unit test your queries (there are probably ways to do this with stored procs, but I've not seen anyone do it)
- Can easily track down where queries are used and remove ones no longer required

When I've joined any project that has a lot of stored procs there are often a lot of them that are not used (or probably not used), but no one dares remove them as no one is sure.

The only time I would start with stored procedures would be if I was working in a corporate environment where access to the database was restricted in such a way that I had to.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing to add: Using **TSQL** you can create a **pack** of queries to be executed as a **unit** to make sure that the access to the rows is locked till you finish your list of queries. As long as I know I think it could not be done using **LINQ**.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
```

This is very useful - for example - when you don't want a new insert to be executed while you executing a list of queries.