# Suggest data access design for Entity Framework (stored procedure less)

Tags: entity-framework, database-design, architecture, entity-framework-4.1

The plan is to use Entity Framework for data access. We are in a dilemma in deciding whether to use stored procedures or not.

The main idea behind avoiding stored procedures: we don't want any one tempted in writing business logic at the database level. I believe in database is only for storage.

Is there any performance hit if I write joins, business logic at the data access level? Is this as good as stored procedures? please provide your recommendations.

Regards,
Ramana Akula.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are SPs redundant if using Linq and EF (best practice)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517891/are-sps-redundant-if-using-linq-and-ef-best-practice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SP disadvantages:

1. SP code is "fixed" - e.g. you don't have LINQ flexibility here. This required extra level of synchronization.
2. Should be written by specialist in most cases. Almost all C# developers historically are not very good in this.
3. Although you put extra effort for SPs maintaining you don't get significant performance improvement
4. Even if you don't have intention, SPs will contain some part of business logic code.
5. If you loose some control over SPs maintenance (or if you'd add some premature optimization to DAL), you'd need more and more SPs as you go: getXbyY, getXbyZ, getSomeFieldByX, geAnotherFieldsByX, etc, etc.

So my opinion is avoiding SPs as possible. If you feel you need one, that could indicate incorrect data/storage structure design.